# How can we use the FPTAS for problem B to solve problem A

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, optimization

Given an optimization problem A which is NP-complete, and can be polynomially reduced to another optimization problem B which is also NP-complete. If we use an [FPTAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme#Deterministic) to solve the reduced problem B' (A $\rightarrow$ B = B'), then under what rules can the solution obtained from solving with the FPTAS be directly associated with a solution to problem A?

For example, Problem A is shortest Path problem and Problem B is knapsack Problem.

Comment: You need the reduction to be *approximation-preserving*.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus : Sorry for the trouble, but do you mind elaborating on it. If example is provided that will be quite helpful. But thanks for the note.

Comment: Wikipedia has some information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation-preserving_reduction.

Answer (score 3):

You need a stronger guarantee on the reduction, that it be [approximation preserving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation-preserving_reduction). Not all reductions are approximation preserving. An extreme example is given by Min Vertex Cover and Max Independent Set. The complement of a vertex cover is an independent set, and so there are simple NP-hardness reductions between these problems. However, while Min Vertex Cover has a 2-approximation algorithm, Max Independent Set cannot be approximated to within $n^{1-\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ unless $\mathsf{P=NP}$.

Answer (score 3):

You don't necessarily have to focus only on an FPTAS, and not even on positive results. The key idea is an approximation-preserving reduction: if you reduce problem A to problem B, then an $\alpha$-approximation algorithm for B implies a $f(\alpha)$-approximation for A, where $f$ is some function. Now observe both of the following are true: if A is hard to approximate, so is B. Also, if you can approximate B, you can also approximate A.

For example, consider an instance $(G,k)$ of chromatic number. Suppose there is a polynomial-time algorithm that, given $(G,k)$, constructs an instance $(G',k')$ of problem X. Moreover, suppose it holds that the size of $G'$ is linear in the size of $G$, $k' = k$, and $(G,k)$ is a YES-instance of chromatic number iff $(G',k')$ is a YES-instance of X. Now, any algorithm approximating problem X is also an approximation algorithm for chromatic number. But in fact, it is known chromatic number cannot be approximated within a factor of $n^{1-\varepsilon}$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$ (unless P = NP). Thus, the same is true for problem X.